# How to convert fbx to usdz with textures

Tags: scenekit, usdz

I am trying to convert fbx file with different textures to usdz but the converters just convert it to usdz without textures. Is there way to correctly convert fbx to usdz with all the textures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I needed to convert just a single fbx then I would probably use Blender to convert it to an .obj, export the textures out then use Reality Converter to make up the USDZ. If it was a bulk operation then perhaps consider trying to use Blender’s internal USDZ export tools, writing a small python script to automate.

Comment: Intersting approach using the mentioned "small python script". Could you provide an info or link where to find such examples?

Comment: I just searched 'batch convert blender', there looked like several options. The tricky thing will be to change this over to USDZ, but it's certainly possible. Check a page like this one https://gist.github.com/HsiaTsing/31361ea018637aa1781c